# read line and keep spaces from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to write in xml file some profiles that i created so far so good ,

the input string is ProfilesList(0) = "45 65 67"
ProfilesList(1) = "profilename";

```
public void CreateGroupXML(String GroupNameWithPath, List<String> ProfilesList)
{
        ProfilesGroup.ProfilesList = ProfilesList;

        XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        ws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
        for (int i = 0; i < ProfilesList.Count; i++)
        {
            ProfilesList[i] += Environment.NewLine;
        }


        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProfilesGroup));
        using (XmlWriter wr = XmlWriter.Create(GroupNameWithPath, ws))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(wr, ProfilesGroup);
        }

    }

}
```

in the xml file the profiles written like that :

```
ProfilesList="45 65 67&#xA; profilename&#xA;
```

So far so good, the problem happens when i trying read from the xml file 
it split the first profile name into 3 
here the code

```
    public List<string> getProfilesOfGroup(string groupNameFullPath)
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = File.OpenRead(groupNameFullPath);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProfilesGroup));
            _ProfilesGroup = (ProfilesGroup)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return _ProfilesGroup.ProfilesList;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            log.ErrorFormat("Exception in getProfilesOfGroup: {0}", Ex.Message);
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Close();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

the output (lets call the string ProfileList) contains :
ProfileList(0) = 45
ProfileList(1) = 65
ProfileList(2) = 67
ProfileList(3) = profilename

and i expecting the string to contain
ProfileList(0) = 45 65 67
ProfileList(1) = profilename
```

edit here the full xml :

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?ProfilesGroup
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ProfilesList="45 65
>   67
>  profilename
> "

and the class:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("VProfilesGroup", IsNullable = false, DataType = "", Namespace = "")]
public class ProfilesGroup
{
    [XmlAttribute("ProfilesList")]
    public List<String> ProfilesList = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: isn't that normal behavior since you are returning a List what happens if you were to return a string[] would  you then only get 2 items vs 4 could you not use a Join() method

Comment: yeah but  i excpect to get a list with lenegth of 2 and not 4

Comment: dbc i edited  please take a look @dbc

Comment: How about showing us some XML?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just remove the `[XmlAttribute("ProfilesList")]` attribute?  Your data will be serialized and deserialized successfully.  The XML will look like:

```
<VProfilesGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ProfilesList>
        <string>45 65 67</string>
        <string>profilename</string>
    </ProfilesList>
</VProfilesGroup>
```

In this format the list of strings is clearly defined to have two entries.  This is the standard way to serialize & deserialize an array of strings with `XmlSerializer`.  Or do you have some external constraint making you declare the list as an attribute?

**Update**

If you must serialize the `ProfilesList` as an attribute not an array of elements, you can manually construct and deconstruct the string like so:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("VProfilesGroup", IsNullable = false, DataType = "", Namespace = "")]
public class ProfilesGroup
{
    static readonly char Delimiter = '\n';

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<String> ProfilesList { get; set; } // Enhance the setter to throw an exception if any string contains the delimiter.

    [XmlAttribute("ProfilesList")]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string ProfilesListText
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(Delimiter.ToString(), ProfilesList.ToArray());
        }
        set
        {
            ProfilesList = new List<string>(value.Split(Delimiter));
        }
    }

    public static string CreateGroupXML(List<String> ProfilesList)
    {
        var group = new ProfilesGroup();
        group.ProfilesList = ProfilesList;
        return XmlSerializationHelper.GetXml(group);
    }

    public static List<string> GetProfilesOfGroup(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProfilesGroup));
        var group = (ProfilesGroup)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        return group == null ? null : group.ProfilesList;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>(new string[] { "45 65 67", "profilename" });
        var xml = CreateGroupXML(list);
        var newList = GetProfilesOfGroup(xml);
        bool same = list.SequenceEqual(newList);
        Debug.Assert(same); // No assert.
    }
}
```

The resulting XML looks like:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<VProfilesGroup xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ProfilesList=\"45 65 67&#xA;profilename\" />
```

In this case, I am testing the code by serializing and deserializing to a string rather than to a file.  And then the helper:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializer serializer) where T : class
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;        // For cosmetic purposes.
            settings.IndentChars = "    "; // The indentation used in the test string.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetXml(obj, serializer);
    }
}
```

Comment: short,summarized,simple answer @dbc, Thanx so much!